# how to show download progress from Firebase Translate Language

Tags: android, firebase, progress-bar, firebase-mlkit

In my app app, I want to display a progress bar for downloading a specific language. Is there someone to help me. this is my code:

```
val options = FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
                .setSourceLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.EN)
                .setTargetLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.FR)
                .build()

        val englishFrenchTranslator = FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options)

        goToTranslate.setOnClickListener {
            actionMessage.text = "Translate ....."

            val condition = FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder().build()
            
            englishFrenchTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded(condition).addOnSuccessListener{
                
                
                englishFrenchTranslator.translate(inputText.text.toString()).addOnSuccessListener {
                    outputText.setText(it)
                    actionMessage.text = "finish ....."

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is your code that defines your UI (and where you want to add a progress bar)? What did you try already?

Comment: Download progress information is not supported by the SDK. Also, we made some changes to Firebase ML Kit to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. "ML Kit"(without firebase branding) contains all the on-device APIs. Here's(https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration) the migration guide from firebase mlkit to mlkit. We are considering adding download progress info support in future releases of mlkit.

Comment: One year and the question is still unanswered ?